# Why do curves get thinner at 90° angles?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

Why do vector curves get smaller at corners?

[image]

In image, the width of the curve at point B (where it turns 90° to the left) is smaller than at point A. This only occurs when cyclic is enabled.

How do I get both points to be the same width without disabling cyclic?

Comment: Welcome to the site :) I've attempted to interpret your question and edit to be more easily read. If you feel I've gotten it wrong or you just don't agree with my edits for some reason, feel free to roll them back or [edit] it again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are beveling a curve in Blender, currently it will happen with the 3D mode because of the algorithm. You have to switch to 2D mode to solve that:

[image]